# Вывести значение ключа JSON

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, requests, словари

Дан JSON файл, нужно вывести значения ключей к этому файлу.
Пример:

```
data = response.json()
print(data)
```

Выдаёт:

```
{'response': [{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'id': 0, 'last_name': 'Durov'}]}
```

Нужно, чтобы вывело значение ключей `first_name`, `id`, `last_name`...
Как это сделать? Помогите, пожалуйста?

Comment: что конкретно не получается? какие-то ошибки? `first_name = data['response'][0]['first_name']`... остальное - по аналогии

Answer (score 4, accepted):

JSON - тот же словарь пайтон, обращайтесь к нему по ключам:

```
data = {'response': [{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'id': 0, 'last_name': 'Durov'}]}

id = data['response'][0]['id']
first_name = data['response'][0]['first_name']
last_name = data['response'][0]['last_name']
```

в итоге:

```
>>> id
0
>>> first_name
'Pavel'
>>> last_name
'Durov'
```

Answer (score 3):

Если разобрать по частям. Т.к. не понятен тип данных для `data` я покажу на одной переменной, которая будет содержать в себе значение ответа:

```
data = {'response': [{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'id': 0, 'last_name': 'Durov'}]}
```

По контексту понятно, что вы используете `requests`-модуль(поправьте, если не так), что при использовании метода `.json()` дает на выходе обычный `dict`.

Итак, у нас есть:

```
>>type(data)
<class 'dict'>
```

Тип данных словарь позволяет обращаться к значениям по ключам, т.е.:

```
>>> data["response"] 
[{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'id': 0, 'last_name': 'Durov'}]
```

А, если посмотреть на тип данных `data["response"]`, то мы получим:

```
>>> type(data["response"]) 
<class 'list'>
```

Список - есть итерируемый объект или `data["response"][0]` даст нам словарь с необходимыми значениями:

```
>>> i_need_this_dict = data["response"][0]
>>> type(i_need_this_dict) 
<class 'dict'>
>>> i_need_this_dict
{'first_name': 'Pavel', 'id': 0, 'last_name': 'Durov'}
```

И в конце пробегаемся по словарю:

```
>>> for key in i_need_this_dict:  
...  print(key, i_need_this_dict[key]) 
... 
first_name Pavel
id 0
last_name Durov
```

Так же можно обращаться и к отдельным ключам-значениям.

Можно так же обратить внимание на специально написанные модули для работы с `json`. Но в большинстве случаев для python'a это все равно будут словари. Я думаю, что обработка словарей и понимание типов данных задачи необходимые